# How do you find parametric equations for other equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on this problem. There is no lesson, I'm trying to teach myself.

Which of the following are NOT parametric equations for the rectangular equation?

y=x^2-2x-3

A. x=t-1; y=t^2-4t
B. x=t+2; y=t^2+2t-3
C. x=t-2; y=t^2-6t-5
D. x=t+3; y=t^2+4t

Answer (score 1):

We can compute, unfortunately possibly $4$ times.

For example, look at A). Substitute $t-1$ for $x$ in $x^2-2x-3$. We get 
$$x^2-2x-3=(t-1)^2-2(t-1)-3=(t^2-2t+1)-2(t-1)-3=t^2-4t.$$
This is the value for $y$ given in A), so A) is a correct parametrization.

Now repeat for B), C), D).

The substitutions and checking may be faster if we use the factorization $x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)$.

There are various shortcuts based on this idea. It is hard to know whether the time investment in looking for shortcuts is worthwhile.

**Remark:** The bad one turns out to be C). For $(t-2)^2-2(t-2)-3=t^2-6t +5$.

Answer (score 0):

For this question just simply plug x and y into the equation for each set of parametric equations when you do not have equality on both sides then it cannot be a parametric equation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the idea of the problem backwards based on your title.  The idea is not to take the equation in x and y and see if you can synthesize the other parametric versions, but rather to take the parametric versions, eliminate the parameter by substitution (solve for t in one equation, plug into the other), and see if you recover the original equation.

Let's try A.

$$x = t-1,\,\, y = t^2 -4t$$
$$t = x+1$$
$$y = (x+1)^2 -4(x+1)$$
$$y = x^2 +2x +1 -4x -4$$
$$y = x^2 -2x -3$$

That one is correct because we recover the original equation.  Let's try C.

$$x = t-2,\,\, y = t^2 -6t -5$$
$$t = x+2$$
$$y = (x+2)^2 -6(x+2)-5$$
$$y = x^2 +4x +4 -6x -12 -5$$
$$y = x^2 -2x -13$$

This one was not correct because it recovers a different equation.

B and D also work out to be correct by the same procedure.  So the answer is C.

An alternative procedure is to get the equation in terms of t only by substituting both x and y, and simplifying until the equality is either true or false.